# phpmyadmin stucks while creating stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a simple stored procedure in phpmyadmin on namecheap.com server. I have created this procedure on my localhost and there was no problem however I'm unable to understand why is it not being created now.

I have tried by using mySQL as well as from Add Routine option.
My table name is `users` and here is the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getUsers (myUsername varchar (32))
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = myUsername;
END$$
```

However I have another table called `albums` and I've written similar procedure for that table and it is working fine. Please help
[Stucks on Loading Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycDZ0.png)

Comment: I'm not sure, but aren't you missing [`DELIMITER $$`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html) and `DELIMITER ;` around the statement?

Comment: @Kenney my version of phpmyadmin has delimiter field so they are not to be added explicitly. Also I tried from "add routine" option but it stucks there too.

Comment: The SELECT statement on your post is different from the one on the picture you add.

Comment: Okay but they both seem legal. All similar statements are running normally except statements related to users table. I've rechecked and I realised that users table exists in database just like other tables

Comment: So which is the "real" SELECT. It's important because maybe the problem is in one variable, column, type, etc.

Comment: Both are correct, I was trying by getting from ID which is integer but it wasn't working, I tried using username which is varchar (32) and that didn't work as well but I wrote a procedure having statement select * from albums where album.ID = parm and it was added normally. So turns out, problem is with users,

Comment: Also, this procedure was working fine on localhost xampp, but it is creating problem on online hosting

Comment: What are the MySQL and phpMyAdmin versions on your localhost and namecheap servers?

Comment: Namecheap has v5.4.36 for PHP and 5.4.45-cll-lve for mySQL and on localhost I have 5.6.8 for PHP and 5.6.24 for mySQL

Comment: After contacting namecheap and telling them about the issue, it appeared that my syntax was perfectly fine, there was a problem on their side and they fixed it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need the `DELIMITER` and `IN` for the params:

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE getUsers (IN myUsername varchar (32))
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = myUsername;
    END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: These are not the problems, I have tried. If delimiter was problem then it should have been added from "add routine" option but when I try from there, it stucks. I've added screenshot with question. Please view.

Comment: Use my script and ran it directly as a query instead of this wizard

Comment: can you guide me more about my script please?

Comment: Also problem is that other queries and scripts are running normally except anything related to users table.

Comment: Its the same thing just that you dont need that tool to create an sp. try because im not sure why it woukd freeze

Comment: After contacting namecheap and telling them about the issue, it appeared that my syntax was perfectly fine, there was a problem on their side and they fixed it for me. Thanks